# Disable use of MacVim keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, macvim

Is there any way to disable keyboard shortcuts in MacVim? I mean the shortcuts like `Cmd + s` for example, I want to convince myself to use things like `:w`, but I can't do so if I can save the file using `Cmd + s`, you get me?

But I of course, still want to use the GUI, so is there any way to disable these, without stoping using the MacVim GUI?

Thanks for your help. BTW I made a Google search and wasn't able to find an answer.

**EDIT:**
Following @ChrisJohnsen's suggestion, I have already tried the following with no success:

```
if has('gui_running')
    macmenu File.Save key=<nop>
    macmenu File.Save\ As\.\.\. key=<nop>
endif
```

**EDIT 2:**
I moved the error I'm getting over to this other question: [When I try to run vim in command line I get Python errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441820/when-i-try-to-run-vim-in-command-line-i-get-python-errors)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no simple way to disable all of the pre-defined Mac-style keyboard shortcuts, but you can definitely change/disable any of them. The important command is `:macmenu` (see `:help :macmenu`); it lets you set the Mac-specific properties of any Vim menu item (mostly Mac-specific keyboard shortcuts and Mac-specific actions (e.g. open/save dialog boxes, window manipulations, etc.)).

```
macmenu File.Save key=<nop>
macmenu File.Save\ All key=<nop>
macmenu File.Save\ As\.\.\. key=<nop>
```

The thing is that `:macmenu` commands are only effective if they are in your `.gvimrc` file.

If you do `:e $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim` and search for `macm`, you will find the list of pre-defined shortcuts and actions. Copy the desired lines to you `.gvimrc` and replace `key=<whatever>` with `key=<nop>`. You can also wrap them in `if has("gui_macvim")` / `endif` if you need your `.gvimrc` to work on multiple platforms.

Comment: I tried it, but for some reason it does not work. I posted in the OP what I've tried. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you put the entries in your `.gvimrc` (g for GUI), not your `.vimrc`? They will only work in `.gvimrc` (and they do work for me).

Comment: I didn't put them in my `.gvimrc`, I put them in my `.vimrc`, however I did enclose it within `if has('gui_running')`, and inside that `if has('gui_macvim')`

Comment: They *must* be in `.gvimrc`; using `has('gui_running')` is not an effective substitute. The problem is that `.vimrc` runs before `menu.vim` where the defaults are assigned (any “overrides” done in `.vimrc` will be undone by `menu.vim`); `.gvimrc` runs after `menu.vim` (any overrides done there will not be undone; `.gvimrc` is basically the last init file to be processed).

Comment: While you are learning to do without Command-s, you might also want to `nnoremap <D-s> <nop>`; otherwise Command-s in normal mode seems to be treated like plain `s` (which works like `cl`: change character(s) to the right).

Comment: I know totally what you mean @ChrisJohnsen I did consider that, but I'm gonna bear with it in order to remind me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

MacVim has only one "advantage" over plain Vim: it supports native Mac OS X shortcuts. If you don't want those shortcuts you might as well simply use plain Vim.

FWIW, when I switched from TextMate I, too, found after a while that these native shortcuts were an obstacle on my way to learning Vim. My solution was to focus my efforts on plain Vim. After a week in the terminal you should be able to completely disregard those shortcuts.

I'd advise you to take a little pause and think about doing things in a more appropriate order:

1. In the terminal, do `$ vimtutor` as many times as needed.
2. In the terminal again, use `$ vim` for simple tasks first then more complex tasks. There's a predictable productivity hit at the beginning but it will last only a few days/weeks.
3. Once you have reached your previous level of productivity, you can start to fly Vim full-time. At that point, using MacVim or GVim or plain `$ vim` *should make no difference whatsoever.*

Bonus points for not relying too much on plugins, other people's vimrcs or "distributions" like janus or spf13…

Comment: I think I'll do that, one reason I didn't is because all my color schemes act really strange with the Terminal, I've tried all sorts of stuff, but doesn't work. I think I'll just train myself to not use shortcuts, unless the question below works.

Comment: Don't worry about colorschemes: the default ones work just as well as the cool ones. Focus on the core parts instead: Ex commands, text objects, motions, macros, substitutions…

Comment: See, the problem is, even the default one looks strange. And I think you can agree that without a color scheme it's kind of hard to code. But, nevertheless, I'm gonna try to fix it, solve it, and follow your tips. :)

Comment: Try `:color desert`, it's easy on the eyes even in a 16 colors terminal.

Comment: Well, as soon as I tried using `vim` in Terminal, I got a Python error, do you know what could be the problem? I added info to the OP.

Comment: This is matter for another question.

Comment: True, I created a question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441820/when-i-try-to-run-vim-in-command-line-i-get-python-errors

Comment: Eh, I think another advantage MacVim has is different cursor styles for different modes. It's a small detail but I always notice its absence in Terminal vim. Were there a way to have those cursor styles in Terminal vim, I'd probably use it exclusively.